Create long exposure images from videos
With the idea of ​​doing false long exposure as found here:

https://petapixel.com/2020/10/19/how-to-use-photoshop-to-turn-video-into-long-exposure-photos/
https://patdavid.net/2013/09/faking-nd-filter-for-long-exposure/
https://nithinbekal.com/posts/long-exposure-video/

I have a set of 934 images extracted from a 30-second video at 29 FPS. I tried the Photoshop method, but it is time consuming and too slow. I'm not very comfortable with programming, but I know how to use the terminal a little bit. With my terminal command, I get this:
C:\Program Files\Hugin\bin>align_image_stack -a C:\Users\strig\Videos\Sequence\1000.jpg 1001.jpg 1002.jpg 1003.jpg 1004.jpg
ERROR: caught exception:
Precondition violation!
Unable to open file '1001.jpg'.
(C:\daten\Hugin\vcpkg\buildtrees\vigra\src\ion-1-11-1-c16c9c8e90\src\impex\codecmanager.cxx:203)

Can somebody help me please?

For each of the images you need to add full path, C:\Users\strig\Videos\Sequence\1001.jpg, C:\Users\strig\Videos\Sequence\1002.jpg, etc

ok that's what I was telling myself

The output says: Unable to open file '1001.jpg'. The program can't open the file because it can't find the file; since you haven't specified the full path, the program assumes that the file is in the current directory, and it's obviously not there. You need to reference files accurately.
I'd also suggest that in general it's safest to enclose file paths in double-quotes, to ensure space characters are interpreted correctly.

yeah also that's what I was telling myself
Something like that?  C:\Program Files\Hugin\bin\align_image_stack -a "C:\Users\strig\Videos\Sequence\1000.jpg 1001.jpg 1002.jpg 1003.jpg 1004.jpg"
i've got C:\Program Files\Hugin\bin>align_image_stack -a "C:\Users\strig\Videos\Sequence\1000.jpg 1001.jpg 1002.jpg 1003.jpg 1004.jpg"
align_image_stack: At least two files need to be specified

Normally, you work in the directory that contains the data, so you do:
cd C:\Users\strig\Videos\Sequence  
align_image_stack -a *.jpg 
# or
align_image_stack -a 1001.jpg 1002.jpg 1003.jpg ....

If Windows complains that it cannot find align_image_stack, then you specify the path to it in the command:
cd C:\Users\strig\Videos\Sequence
C:\Program Files\Hugin\bin\align_image_stack -a *.jpg 


yes I realized it later, but I don't know how to point to the directory
Translated from french with google:
which is normal since I either don't have the align_image_stack application in my images directory, or I don't have the images in the hugin application directory

so I used the append command found here [meta]https://github.com/security-cheatsheet/cmd-command-cheat-sheet
C:\Program Files\Hugin\bin>align_image_stack -a append "C:\Users\strig\Videos\Sequence\1000.jpg 1001.jpg 1002.jpg 1003.jpg 1004.jpg"
align_image_stack: At least two files need to be specified

This is the purpose of the cd command. This makes your working directory the directory with the pictures, so if there is no path information in the file names they are implicitly taken from that directory. And to use the command , either it is in a directory in your PATH and you can just use the command name, or it's not and you have to give a full path to it.

after several unsuccessful attempts I copied the images into the folder and this is the result of the order
!https://ibb.co/KwBrXtj

Yes because applications are prevented from writing files in a sensitive directory where you keep code. You have to keep them in separate directories. I can only help if you follow my instructions, not if you adlib on them. And this is no longer a photography problem, you will get more complete answers in a forum dedicated to Windows and its command line.

Yes because applications are prevented from writing files in a sensitive directory where you keep code. You have to keep them in separate directories. ok I understand your remark very well, that's why I originally created a separate folder to work in. I can only help if you follow my instructions, not if you adlib on them. I understand, only when I tried your commands this is what it gives me a screen from my terminal
